# bash script that dynamically calls argument as another bash script

Tags: linux, bash

I want to implement a bash script that acts the following way

```
./script_a.sh script_b.sh $arg1 $arg2 ...
```

./script_a.sh would invoke script_b.sh on $arg1 $arg2... $argn
I don't know how many args there are beforehand.  how can this be one?

Comment: is `script_b.sh` already implemented, or is this a fresh design? If it is, why would you want to do it this way?

Answer (score 4):

Try this as a wrapper:

```
#!/bin/bash
"$@"
```

Answer (score 0):

The `$@` contains the list of all arguments passed to the script.

For example consider:

```
-sh-3.2$ cat scripta
echo $@
"./$@"

-sh-3.2$ cat scriptb
echo hello world $@

-sh-3.2$ bash scripta scriptb 1 2 3 4
scriptb 1 2 3 4
hello world 1 2 3 4
```

`"./$@"` calls the script in the argument, `scriptb` with the remaining arguments `1 2 3 4`

`hello world 1 2 3 4` is obtained on running the second sript, `scriptb`